# Execute script mongo with external file and use pretty

Tags: mongodb

I want execute a Query in mongo db with external file.js

I did Try this:

```
mongo < query.js
```

or

```
cat query.js| mongo
```

These methods works, but i like to have `pretty()`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the mongo command supports a script argument:

```
mongo file.js
```

This will execute `file.js` in a mongo shell. You don't have to perform IO redirections or pipes to accomplish this.

---

Regarding the `pretty()` command - the mongo shell defines a function called `printjson()` which does exactly what `pretty()` does: it prints a formatted object including indentations and line breaks. Basically it formats the JSON before outputting it.

Taken from [the docs:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

> ...In scripts, either use the JavaScript `print()` function or the **mongo** specific `printjson()` function which returns formatted JSON.

Comment: thanks! i have this [file](http://pastebin.com/D4qsAvQG) with name `pippo.js`. If I do `mongo pippo.js` I have an error `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
2014-07-18T11:10:16.588+0200 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at pippo.js
failed to load: pippo.js`
with `mongo < pippo.js`or `cat pippo.js | mongo`, works